# default data on page init angular 4

Tags: angular, default, dropdown

I have a button in view which has a dropdown of different names that I retrieve from backend. I'm showing the first name that I retrieve as default. I have a method in component to get data when they change options in dropdown. I added a click event and that is retrieving data when option is changed in dropdown.

I'm able to get data form getFinalData when I change options in dropdown since I have click event on that. But I want to show the data of first item when the initial page loads. How do I show the data of first name on ngOninit?

component.ts

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.getFinalData(this.name);
}
getnames() {
  this.http.get("**").subscribe(data => {});
}
getFinalData(name) {
  this.http.get("**" + "/" + name).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

html

```html
<button id="selected" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{{selected}}</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu arrow form-group">
    <a class="dropdown-item" *ngFor="let data of data" (click)="getFinalData(data?.name)">{{data?.name}}
    </a>
  </div>
</button>
```

Comment: Where is default data kept?  you can use the 'first' option to show the first item in your ngFor.  like this:  <a *ngFor="let data of data; let firstData = first;">{{(firstData? data.name : '')}}</a>

Comment: I'm able to show first item in the dropdown button. I want to show the data associated with first item by default

Comment: is that data from 'getFinalData'?  I don't know where/how your default data is stored

Comment: yes, I get the data from getFinalData. I'm able to get data when I change options in dropdown since I have click event on that. But I want to show the data of first item when the initial page loads

Comment: Sorry but this is not very clear.  How are you populating your dropDown?  Is there another function that brings that info in?  It seems now that this.name is set when you click the dropdown, but that also seems to be populated from the same call so I'm not sure how this is working.  Can you show all of your code?

Comment: Yes the list of names, I'm getting form other method. I edited the question. Please check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169777/discussion-between-yer-and-farasi78).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.getNames();
      }

getnames() {
    this.http.get('**')
      .subscribe(namesData => {
      if(this.name==""){
        //assume that this.name is "" or null on init.
          this.getFinalData(namesData[0].name)
          .subscribe(nameInfo=>{})
       }
 });

    getFinalData(name) {
              this.http.get('**' + '/' + name)
              .subscribe(data => {
               console.log(data)
            }

   onSelectClick(name:string){
      this.getFinalData(name)
   }
```